# How to find height of BST iteratively?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

```
  public void HeightIterative()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int counter2 = 0;
        TreeNode current=root;

        if(current != null)
        {
            while(current.LeftNode!=null)
            {
                counter++;
                current = current.LeftNode;
            }
            while(current.RightNode!=null)
            {
                counter2++;
                current = current.RightNode;
            }
        }

        int res = 1+Math.Max(counter, counter2);
        Console.WriteLine("The Height Of Tree Is: "+res);
    }
```

I wrote iterative method, to calculate height of tree. but in some cases its not working properly. As in case:
10
1
2
3
4
5
18
17
16
15
14
13
what's the problem. according to this sequence height of tree is 6 where as my code is showing 5.

Comment: **Must** be iterative, BST, BFS....homework?

Comment: not a homework! if it is then i mentioned it using homework tag

Comment: Why are you insisting on using an iterative approach rather than recursion then?

Comment: what if u have a text file with 100000 elements & you want to store it in a binary tree. then want to know height of tree. if u do this recursively, then stackoverflow exception occurs. thats the reason

Comment: 100000 elements in the balanced binary tree is the log(100000)/log(2) ~ 20 recursive calls. Wheris no a posibility to stackoverflow exception.

Comment: dude make a file with random 100000 integers, try it, then post any thing here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using two loops, but each loop investigated only oneside of node, but each node in tree has two sides you should investigate it all. You can do it through recursion call.

```
private int GetLen(TreeNode node)
{
  var result = 0;

  if(node != null)
  {
    result = Math.Max(GetLen(node.LeftNode), GetLen(node.RightNode)) + 1;
  }

  return result;
}

public void HeightIterative()
{
  int res = GetLen(root);
  Console.WriteLine("The Height Of Tree Is: "+res);
}
```

Iterative version:

```
private class NodeInfo
{
  public NodeInfo(TreeNode node, int len)
  {
    Node = node;
    Len = len;
  }

  public TreeNode Node {get; private set;}
  public int Len {get; private set;}
}

public void HeightIterative()
{
    int maxLen = 0;

    var queue = new Queue<NodeInfo>();
    queue.Enqueue(new NodeInfo(root, 1));

    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        var item = queue.Dequeue();
        var current = item.Node;
        var currentLen = item.Len;

        if (current.LeftNode != null)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(new NodeInfo(current.LeftNode, currentLen + 1));
        }

        if (current.RightNode != null)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(new NodeInfo(current.RightNode, currentLen + 1));
        }

        if (currentLen > maxLen)
        {
            maxLen = currentLen;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The Height Of Tree Is: " + maxLen);
}
```

Comment: dude i mentioned i need iterative version.

Comment: I don't know how to implement it :) It will be complicated to understand. But I'll try :)

Comment: Is the TreeNode has Parent property?

Comment: You can check iterative version

Comment: Just a simple container for two or more values. It introduced from the DN 4.0 if you are using previous DN version you can create you own class or use KayValuePair<>

Comment: for using tuple, would i have to add any namespace?

Comment: I don't remember that name space is required, code was updated to avoid tuple utilization.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way that does not require any extra space except the queue for storing the nodes.

1. Add child nodes of a current element and remember size of the queue.
2. Let each dequeue call decrement the counter
3. When counter reaches zero that means we are done with current level.
4. Repeat and count number of times counter reaches zero - this is the depth/height of the tree

Code goes like this :

```
public int treeDepth(Node root){
    int height = 0;
    int counterNodesInLevel = 1;

    if(root!=null)
    {
        Queue<Node> queue=new Queue<Node>()
        queue.enqueue(root);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()){
            Node current = queue.dequeue();
            counterNodesInLevel -= 1;

            if(current.left!=null){
               queue.enqueue(current.left)
            }

            if(current.right!=null){
               queue.enqueue(current.right)
            }

            if (counterNodesInLevel == 0){
                height += 1;
                counterNodesInLevel = queue.Size();
            }                    
        }    
    }    
    return height;
}
```

Time complexity is O(N), space complexity is O(N)

Comment: the dequeue inside the if statements should be enqueue. I submitted an edit (also changed some variable names to make it more clear). Other than that: good answer!

Answer (score 1):

The problem:

You are finding the depth of the left-most node in the first loop, and the right-most in the second, and never interrogating any node that involves going down to the left AND the right.

A solution:

Have a single loop that drills down the left nodes, but adds each right node that it 'skips' into a queue.  When you run out of left nodes, pop-off a node form your queue and continue on until the queue becomes empty.  You'll need to store the height of each node you put in the queue with that node.

Comment: Not as described, since you always go down the left child.  But its only depth-first if the queue if FILO (i.e. a stack); if the queue is FIFO, then you get something in between.

Answer (score -2):

```
public int Height()
    {
        int result = GetMaxHeight(this.Root,0);
        return result;
    }

    private int GetMaxHeight(Node<T> node,int count)
    {
        int leftMax = 0, rightMax = 0;
        if (node.Left != null)
        {
            leftMax = GetMaxHeight(node.Left, count+1);
        }
        if (node.Right != null)
        {
            rightMax = GetMaxHeight(node.Right, count + 1);
        }

        if(node.Left==null && node.Right == null)
        {
            return count;
        }

        return Math.Max(leftMax,rightMax);
    }
```