# Iterative vs recursive solution in BST

Tags: c#, data-structures

```
public double FindMin()
{
    Node current = root;
    while (!(current.left == null))
        current = current.left;
    return current.Data;
}

public double FindMax()
{
    Node current = root;
    while (!(current.right == null))
        current = current.right;
    return current.Data;
}
```

This is an iterative solution of my Binary search tree's functions to find out minimum and maximum value in a tree in C#. I want to change it to recursive but that code doesn't seem right here

```
public double RecurfindMax(Node current)
{
    //current = root;
    if (current.left == null)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    //if (current.left != null)
    {
        return RecurfindMax(current = current.left);
        //return current;
    }
```

So can you tell me what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check [How to find height of BST iteratively?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8389232/535275) for a similar problem; the solutions there should be instructive.

Also, for your recursive solution, it should raise a red flag that it NEVER considers the right child.

Comment: thanks i got the idea that problem with recursive is because of flag..thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    private Node FindMinRecHelper(Node current)
    {
        if (current.LeftNode == null)
        {
            return current;
        }
        else
        {
            return FindMinRecHelper(current.LeftNode);
        }
    }

    public void FindMinRec()
    {
        Node current = FindMinRecHelper(root);
        Console.WriteLine(current.Data);
    }
```

here the true implementation of RECURSIVE FIND MIN.