# Height of binary search tree iteratively

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

I was trying out an iterative method to find the height/depth of a binary search tree. 
Basically, I tried using Breadth First Search to calculate the depth, by using a Queue to store the tree nodes and using just an integer to hold the current depth of the tree. Each node in the tree is queued, and it is checked for child nodes. If child nodes are present, then the depth variable is incremented. Here is the code:

```
public void calcDepthIterative() {
    Queue<TreeNode> nodeQ = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
    TreeNode node = root;
    int level = 0;
    boolean flag = false;

    nodeQ.add(node);
    while(!nodeQ.isEmpty()) {
        node = nodeQ.remove();
        flag = false;
        if(node.leftChild != null) {
            nodeQ.add(node.leftChild);
            flag = true;
        }

        if(node.rightChild != null) {
            nodeQ.add(node.rightChild);
            flag = true;
        }
        if(flag) level++;
    }
    System.out.println(level);

}
```

However, the code doesn't work for all cases. For example, for the following tree:

```
     10
   /    \
  4      18
   \    /  \
    5  17   19
```

It shows the depth as 3, instead of 2.
I did an alternate version of it using an additional Queue to store the current depths, using the idea in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389232/how-to-find-height-of-bst-iteratively?answertab=votes#tab-top). I wanted to avoid using an additional queue so I tried to optimize it. Here is the code which works, albeit using an additional Queue.

```
public void calcDepthIterativeQueue() {
    Queue<TreeNode> nodeQ = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
    Queue<Integer> lenQ = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    TreeNode node = root;
    nodeQ.add(node);
    lenQ.add(0);
    int maxLen = 0;
    while(!nodeQ.isEmpty()) {
        TreeNode curr = nodeQ.remove();
        int currLen = lenQ.remove();
        if(curr.leftChild != null) {
            nodeQ.add(curr.leftChild);
            lenQ.add(currLen + 1);
        }

        if(curr.rightChild != null) {
            nodeQ.add(curr.rightChild);
            lenQ.add(currLen + 1);
        }
        maxLen = currLen > maxLen ? currLen : maxLen;
    }
    System.out.println(maxLen);

}
```

**QUESTION:**

Is there a way to fix the first method such that it returns the right depth?

**EDIT**
**SEE ACCEPTED ANSWER BELOW**

**Java code for rici's answer:**

```
public void calcDepthIterative() {
    Queue<TreeNode> nodeQ = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
    int depth = 0;
    nodeQ.add(root);
    while(!nodeQ.isEmpty()) {
        int nodeCount = nodeQ.size();
        if(nodeCount == 0)
            break;
        depth++;
        while(nodeCount > 0) {
            TreeNode topNode = nodeQ.remove();
            if(topNode.leftChild != null)
                nodeQ.add(topNode.leftChild);
            if(topNode.rightChild != null)
                nodeQ.add(topNode.rightChild);
            nodeCount--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(depth);
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely positive, but I assume you're counting the cumulative depths of subtrees, not the maximum depth of a subtree, since you potentially increase the counter variable in every subtree instead of once per level.

Comment: The first method is counting the number of nodes with children, which can grow geometrically with respect to the maximum tree depth.  It seems fundamentally flawed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
Create a Queue, and push the root onto it.
Let Depth = 0
Loop:
    Let NodeCount = size(Queue)
    If NodeCount is 0:
        return Depth.
    Increment Depth.
    While NodeCount > 0:
        Remove the node at the front of the queue.
        Push its children, if any, on the back of the queue
        Decrement NodeCount.
```

### How it works

Every time `NodeCount` is set, the scan is just about to start a new row. NodeCount is set to the number of Nodes in that row. When all of those Nodes have been removed (i.e., NodeCount is decremented to zero), then the row has been completed and all the children of nodes on that row have been added to the queue, so the queue once again has a complete row, and NodeCount is again set to the number of Nodes in that row.

Comment: It can not return a right answer for a tree with only one node.

Comment: @chasefornone: why not? At the beginning you push the one node onto the queue, whose size is then 1, which will be the first value of NodeCount. Depth is incremented to 1, and the while loop pops the single node, pushing nothing. Then in the next loop, Depth (1) is returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int height(Node root){
  int ht =0;
  if(root==null) return ht;
  Queue<Node> q = new ArrayDeque<Node>();
  q.addLast(root);
  while(true){
      int nodeCount = q.size();
      if(nodeCount==0) return ht;
      ht++;
      while(nodeCount>0){
       Node node = q.pop();
       if(node.left!=null) q.addLast(node.left);
       if(node.right!=null) q.addLast(node.right);
       nodeCount--;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

How about recurtion,

```
int Depth(Node node)
{
    int depthR=0,depthL=0;
    if(Right!=null)depthR=Depth(Right);
    if(Left!=null)depthL=Depth(Left);
    return Max(depthR,depthL)+1;
}
```

If tou want a zero based depth, just subtract the resulting depth by 1.

Comment: He is discussing an iterative approach, not recursive.

Comment: 1. Not iterative. 2. I think there is a cleaner version for recursion in comparison to this.